# Storing OAuth Credentials

Tags: apex, oauth, security-token

I have the following issue and need an advice on how to approach it.

I connect to a third party system which generates a JWT token. The problem is that the token expires every 15 minutes and I'am not allowed to refresh it constantly due to the authentication system.

Heres a breakdown:

- Token is too long 700 characters and can't be stored in a custom setting/custom metadata type.
- Even if I split the token in a few fields I'am still not able to refresh and store it before it expires because you are not allowed to have a DML and a callout in the same transaction.

I don't really want to use a custom object just for the token but is there any other solution here?

Comment: You can have Callout + DML in the same transaction. Callout just has to come first.

Comment: And what is problem with creating 3 fields to store token? I have seen that couple of times in different managed packages

Comment: Moving the callout at the start wouldn't be useful as I need to be checking if the token is still valid at the beginning. Otherwise I'll be trying to connect with expired credentials.

Comment: If only you could update [`Named Credentials`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) from `Apex`, they'd be a good fit here. I'm not sure either way if it's possible.

Comment: What is also possible to do -- save last callout date/time and in case if that is more than 15 minutes ago -- get new credentials. Also, next case may take a place -- do regular callout, and in case if token expired -- refresh token and repeat callout. As long as those are not in loops -- it should work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so you can actually update the `OAuth Token` for a `Named Credential` using the `Metadata API`. If you install the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), you can push the new token with an additional callout, and not even worry about mixing callouts and DML (though it would be fine if you put the DML at the end).

Anyway, your code would look something like:

```
// retrieve new token value

MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credential';
credential.label = 'Demo Credential';
credential.endpoint = 'https://www.demo.com';
credential.principalType = 'Anonymous';
credential.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
credential.oauthToken = newTokenValue;

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.updateMetadata(
    new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { credential }
);
```

I checked and this `OAuthToken` field does support values of 700 characters.

Comment: I will def try that, never used the wrapper before. Thanks!

Comment: @KostadinStoev Just make sure you check the option on the `Named Credential` to allow merge fields in your headers and you can use [Merge Fields for Apex Callouts That Use Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm).