# Set OAuthToken Without Apex Metadata Wrapper?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, namedcredentials

In working through an answer to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/165525/2995), I found that I can set the `oauthToken` value on a `NamedCredential` using an Apex wrapper for the Metadata API. However, as far as I am aware, that still involves installing [a specific managed package](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), unless you want to roll your own wrapper.

Is there any other way to update the `oauthToken`?

## Apex Metadata API Wrapper

No problem setting this field via `Apex`:

```
MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credential';
credential.label = 'Demo Credential';
credential.endpoint = 'https://www.demo.com';
credential.principalType = 'Anonymous';
credential.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
credential.oauthToken = '<newTokenValue>';

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.updateMetadata(
    new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { credential }
);
```

## UI

While I was able to update it via `Apex`, this field is not available to read or edit in the UI.

[image: Named Credential Edit: Demo Credential]

## IDE

While I was able to add `NamedCredential` to my `package.xml` file, I was not able to push it back to the server using `MavensMate` (Mac).

[image: Demo_Credential Metadata]

## Workbench

I played around with the `Deploy` action but was not able to get anything working there either. I'm not super familiar with how that interface is supposed to work.

[image: Developer Workbench Metadata Deploy]

Comment: seems like by design `named credentials` is supposed to mask from the admin/developer the acquisition/lifecycle of the oauth token, I am not surprised.

Comment: But it's nigh impossible to *set* for the average admin. :( And it's actually pretty easy to view the token value anyway for anyone who has an IDE.

Comment: I'm not sure what "long term" means on the roadmap, potentially Winter '18, but a REST API for Metadata Deploy and Retrieve operations is coming to an org near you some time soon.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - How are you viewing the token. I tried in 3 different IDE's and it is not returning it. Must be setting it wrong or something. I would like to verify that the JS does indeed update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it actually puts a new oAuth token as I cannot query it via dev console but it does successfully update from VF:

May not be what you wanted, not sure, but maybe it will help

```
<apex:page id="NamedCredUpdate">

    <script>
        var sessionId = '{!$API.Session_ID}';
        function sendMetadataRequest(request, callback) {
            var binding = new XMLHttpRequest();

            binding.open('POST', location.protocol+'//'+location.host+ '/services/Soap/m/37.0');
            binding.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
            binding.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            binding.onreadystatechange =
                    function () {
                        if (this.readyState == 4) {
                            var parser = new DOMParser();
                            var doc = parser.parseFromString(this.response, 'application/xml');
                            console.log(doc);

                            var errors = doc.getElementsByTagName('errors');
                            var faultstring = '';
                            var messageText = '';

                            faultstring = doc.getElementsByTagName('faultstring');

                            if (faultstring.length != 0) {
                                messageText = faultstring[0].innerHTML;
                            } else {
                                for (var errorIdx = 0; errorIdx < errors.length; errorIdx++)
                                    messageText += errors.item(errorIdx).getElementsByTagName('message').item(0).innerHTML + '<br/>';
                            }

                            callback(
                                    messageText == '' ? doc : 'Error Making Configuration Changes: ' + messageText

                            );

                        }
                    };
            binding.send(request);

        }

        function updateNamedCredential(credName, callback) {
            var request =
                    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
                    '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">' +
                    '<env:Header>' +
                    '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                    '<urn:sessionId>' + sessionId + '</urn:sessionId>' +
                    '</urn:SessionHeader>' +
                    '</env:Header>' +
                    '<env:Body>' +
                    '<upsertMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">' +
                    '<metadata xsi:type="NamedCredential">' +
                    '<oauthToken>{!$API.Session_ID}</oauthToken>' +
                    '<fullName>' + credName + '</fullName>' +
                    '<label>' + credName + '</label>' +
                    '<endpoint>https://www.google.com</endpoint>' +
                    '<principalType>Anonymous</principalType>' +
                    '<protocol>NoAuthentication</protocol>' +
                    '</metadata>' +
                    '</upsertMetadata>' + '</env:Body>' + '</env:Envelope>';

            sendMetadataRequest(request, callback);
        }


    </script>

    <apex:form>
        <button type="button" onclick="updateNamedCredential('MyTest', function(msg){console.log(msg)});">Click Me</button>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: [Moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56569/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-set-oauthtoken-without-apex-metadata-wrapper).

Comment: Damn, it's a busy time for me. Sorry I wasn't on top of this whole situation. I still haven't had time to vet.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - You ever get this resolved?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it's dropped off everyone's priority list for the time being. :( I will get back to it, but it may be another month yet.

Comment: Of course as soon as I go to test it, I find out someone refreshed the sandbox without talking to anyone. :( It's going to take me a while to restore my work.

Answer (score 1):

I've generated a bare bones Apex class to use WebServiceCallout.invoke to update the NamedCredential.

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
//Warning: '<xsd:anyType>' element anyType has been converted to string in CustomMetadataValue
//Warning: '<xsd:anyType>' element anyType has been converted to string in FieldValue
//Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement
//Methods Included: updateMetadata
//Methods Excluded: cancelDeploy, checkDeployStatus, checkRetrieveStatus, createMetadata, deleteMetadata, deploy, deployRecentValidation, describeMetadata, describeValueType, listMetadata, readMetadata, renameMetadata, retrieve, upsertMetadata
// Primary Port Class Name: MetadataPort    
public class MetadataService {
    public class AllOrNoneHeader_element {
        public Boolean allOrNone;
        private String[] allOrNone_type_info = new String[]{'allOrNone','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'allOrNone'};
    }
    public class CallOptions_element {
        public String client;
        private String[] client_type_info = new String[]{'client','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'client'};
    }
    public class Error {
        public MetadataService.ExtendedErrorDetails[] extendedErrorDetails;
        public String[] fields;
        public String message;
        public String statusCode;
        private String[] extendedErrorDetails_type_info = new String[]{'extendedErrorDetails','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','ExtendedErrorDetails','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] fields_type_info = new String[]{'fields','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] message_type_info = new String[]{'message','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] statusCode_type_info = new String[]{'statusCode','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','StatusCode','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'extendedErrorDetails','fields','message','statusCode'};
    }

    //Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement
    public class ExtendedErrorDetails {
        public String extendedErrorCode;
        public List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElement;
        private String[] extendedErrorCode_type_info = new String[]{'extendedErrorCode','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','ExtendedErrorCode','1','1','false'};
        private String[] anyElement_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','List<DOM.XmlNode>','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'extendedErrorCode','anyElement'};
    }
    public virtual class Metadata {
        public String fullName;
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName'};
    }
    public class MetadataPort {
        public String endpoint_x = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/39.0';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        public MetadataService.SessionHeader_element SessionHeader;
        private String SessionHeader_hns = 'SessionHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
        public MetadataService.CallOptions_element CallOptions;
        private String CallOptions_hns = 'CallOptions=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
        public MetadataService.AllOrNoneHeader_element AllOrNoneHeader;
        private String AllOrNoneHeader_hns = 'AllOrNoneHeader=http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata';
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','MetadataService'};

        public MetadataService.SaveResult[] updateMetadata(MetadataService.Metadata[] metadata) {
            MetadataService.updateMetadata_element request_x = new MetadataService.updateMetadata_element();
            MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.metadata = metadata;
            Map<String, MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                '',
                'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',
                'updateMetadata',
                'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',
                'updateMetadataResponse',
                'MetadataService.updateMetadataResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.result;
        }
    }
    public class SaveResult {
        public MetadataService.Error[] errors;
        public String fullName;
        public Boolean success;
        private String[] errors_type_info = new String[]{'errors','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','Error','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] success_type_info = new String[]{'success','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','boolean','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'errors','fullName','success'};
    }
    public class SessionHeader_element {
        public String sessionId;
        private String[] sessionId_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'sessionId'};
    }
    public class updateMetadata_element {
        public MetadataService.Metadata[] metadata;
        private String[] metadata_type_info = new String[]{'metadata','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','Metadata','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'metadata'};
    }
    public class updateMetadataResponse_element {
        public MetadataService.SaveResult[] result;
        private String[] result_type_info = new String[]{'result','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','SaveResult','0','-1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'result'};
    }

     public class NamedCredential extends Metadata {
        public String type = 'NamedCredential';
        public String fullName;
        private String[] fullName_type_info = new String[]{'fullName','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        public String authProvider;
        public String certificate;
        public String endpoint;
        public String label;
        public String oauthRefreshToken;
        public String oauthScope;
        public String oauthToken;
        public String password;
        public String principalType;
        public String protocol;
        public String username;
        private String[] authProvider_type_info = new String[]{'authProvider','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] certificate_type_info = new String[]{'certificate','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] endpoint_type_info = new String[]{'endpoint','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] label_type_info = new String[]{'label','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] oauthRefreshToken_type_info = new String[]{'oauthRefreshToken','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] oauthScope_type_info = new String[]{'oauthScope','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] oauthToken_type_info = new String[]{'oauthToken','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] password_type_info = new String[]{'password','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] principalType_type_info = new String[]{'principalType','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] protocol_type_info = new String[]{'protocol','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'1','1','false'};
        private String[] username_type_info = new String[]{'username','http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata','true','false'};
        private String[] type_att_info = new String[]{'xsi:type'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'fullName', 'authProvider','certificate','endpoint','label','oauthRefreshToken','oauthScope','oauthToken','password','principalType','protocol','username'};
    }
}
```

Usage is identical to the Metadata Service wrapper (as they are both generated from the WSDL) but is solely focused on updating NamedCredential records.

```
MetadataService.NamedCredential credential = new MetadataService.NamedCredential();
credential.fullName = 'Demo_Credential';
credential.label = 'Demo Credential';
credential.endpoint = 'https://www.demo.com';
credential.principalType = 'Anonymous';
credential.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
credential.oauthToken = '<newTokenValue>';

MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.endpoint_x = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/39.0';
service.updateMetadata(
    new List<MetadataService.Metadata> { credential }
);
System.assertEquals(1, results.size());
MetadataService.SaveResult sr = results[0];
System.debug(sr);
System.assert(sr.success);
```

---

I also deployed the following package, which didn't report any errors and was confirmed to update the NamedCredential.MasterLabel

**Zip Structure**

- package.xml
- namedCredentials/Demo_Credential.namedCredential

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Demo_Credential</members>
        <name>NamedCredential</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

**Demo_Credential.namedCredential**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NamedCredential xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <endpoint>https://www.demo.com</endpoint>
    <label>Demo Credential</label>
    <principalType>Anonymous</principalType>
    <protocol>NoAuthentication</protocol>
    <oauthToken>TestToken</oauthToken>
</NamedCredential>
```